# emberjs nothing handled the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I tried reproducing the search field like they display at [emberjs.com](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/#toc_storing-application-properties) however for some reason my code keeps producing the following error (in google chrome) when entering a query and pressing either enter or clicking the submit button:

```
Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'MyApp.ApplicationController.doSearch'.
```

The code I am working with can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/Mn2yy/

Can someone explain why this error is occuring and what I need to do in order to solve it?

Edit: for if the link goes down, these are the relevant parts of the code:

searchpage route:

```
MyApp.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('searchQuery', this.get('query'));
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('searchpage', { into: 'container' });
    }
});
```

Applicationcontroller:

```
MyApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    // the initial value of the `search` property
    search: '',

    doSearch: function() {
        // the current value of the text field
        var query = this.get('search');
        this.transitionToRoute('search', { query: query });
    }
});
```

and the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="container">
    <button {{action "doSearch" target="MyApp.ApplicationController"}} rel="tooltip-bottom" title="search" class="icon"><i class="icofont-search"></i></button>
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="MyApp.ApplicationController.search" action="MyApp.ApplicationController.doSearch"}}

    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="searchpage">
    <h1>Search</h1>
    {{#linkTo "home"}}Homepage{{/linkTo}}
    <p>You searched for: "{{searchQuery}}"</p>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant parts of the code in the question, please? Don't just link to a jsFiddle, if that link goes dead then the question loses all value. Also worth explaining what you're doing to produce the error (I assume entering text in the box and clicking the button next to it?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use absolute paths for bindings, targets etc. like `MyApp.ApplicationController.search`.

Since you declared both the `search` property and the `doSearch` action on the application controller, just simply type: `{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="search" action="doSearch"}}`

Comment: The first error has gone, however now I have the error "Uncaught More objects were passed than dynamic segments" Do you know how to solve that? I suppose it has something to do with the doSearch function but in every way I try to solve it I produce more errors

Comment: It is because you declared the `path` for the route `search` as `/search` and not `/search/:query` - basically without dynamic segment (`:seach`). But you're still passing some: `this.transitionToRoute('search', { query: query });`. Here the `{ query: query }` is the data for the (non-existent) dynamic segments. Just do `this.transitionToRoute('search')` and you'll get rid of the error.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, I tried using this.transitionToRoute('search'), however my search template still won't show the search-term I've searched for, what do I need to modify in my searchRoute for this to work?

Comment: Could you create another question for this? I think we're getting a bit far from the original question.

Comment: Have to agree with that, made a followup question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014743/emberjs-how-to-handle-transitionto