# EmberJS how to handle transitionTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have the following code which calls an transitionToRoute('search') when a search-query is entered and the enter button is pressed or submit button is clicked.

However, my Router still won't show the searchQuery in the template where it says:

`<p>You searched for: "{{searchQuery}}"</p>`

and the URL looks like `http://www.example.com/#/search/[object Object]` when searching for something (which doesn't seem right to me).

(full code can be viewed over at: http://jsfiddle.net/Mn2yy/1/)
This is the relevant code:

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="container">
    <button {{action "doSearch"}} rel="tooltip-bottom" title="search" class="icon"><i class="icofont-search"></i></button>
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="search" action="doSearch"}}

    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="searchpage">
    <h1>Search</h1>
    {{#linkTo "home"}}Homepage{{/linkTo}}
    <p>You searched for: "{{searchQuery}}"</p>
</script>
```

Application controller:

```
MyApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    // the initial value of the `search` property
    search: '',

    doSearch: function() {
        // the current value of the text field
        var query = this.get('search');
        this.transitionToRoute('search');
    }
});
```

and the Searchpage route:

```
MyApp.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('searchQuery', this.get('query'));
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('searchpage', { into: 'container' });
    }
});
```

Comment: Not a full answer, but you will need to retrieve your search term from the application controller as in my forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DCrHG/2/

Comment: I'd like to mark it as an answer, but I'd also like to know how to solve the [object Object] URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to define the dynamic segment in the router for the search route:

```
MyApp.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("home", { path: "/" });
    this.route("search", { path: "/search/:query" })
});
```

Then you set the `searchQuery` property on the application in the `doSearch` action. You also pass the `query` variable to the `transitionToRoute` method, since it'll fill in the dynamic segment.

```
MyApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    // the initial value of the `search` property
    search: '',

    doSearch: function() {
        // the current value of the text field
        var query = this.get('search');
        this.set('searchQuery', query);
        this.transitionToRoute('search', query);
    }
});
```

Since you need to access this property from the `App.SearchController` instance, you need to wire the 2 controllers together by using the `needs` API:

```
MyApp.SearchController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    application: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application')
});
```

*Aliased the `controllers.application` property to just `application`, to avoid too much typing eg. in the template.*

Then you bind to this property in the `search` template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="searchpage">
    <h1>Search</h1>
    {{#linkTo "home"}}Homepage{{/linkTo}}
    <p>You searched for: "{{application.searchQuery}}"</p>
</script>
```

Last step: if you refresh the page at this point, `searchQuery` won't be automatically populated from the URL. Let's just fix that with the `deserialize` hook:

```
MyApp.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  
    deserialize: function(params) {
        this.controllerFor('application').setProperties({
            searchQuery: params.query,
            search: params.query
        });
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('searchpage', { into: 'container' });
    }
});
```

This will get the params from the URL and set up the application controller with the value of the `query` key.

That's pretty much it, hope I didn't miss anything!

Comment: Thank you very much! you explained very clearly how it works, from now on I'll be able to do it myself :)

Comment: Yw. One last note: I'd probably keep search-related properties on `App.SearchController` and the `doSearch` action on the `App.ApplicationRoute`. Then I'd refer to the search controller *from* the application controller using the needs API. (Basically reverse the current relationship.) This will give you the benefit of using the `doSearch` action anywhere in the appplication without further setup besides the benefit of keeping search-related logic in one (obvious) place.